# Passenger starting error with -e production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

When I start passenger with

source ./railsenv.sh; passenger start -p 50060 -e production -d

however, there are errors ,when I switch to source ./railsenv.sh; passenger start -p 50060  -d. it is OKAY.

Anybody has some ideas?

ENV:

rails: 3.2.13

passenger: 3.09

ruby 1.9.2

---

production.rb in enviroments:

# Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

---

Errors:

***[ pid=11397 thr=13479140 file=utils.rb:176 time=2013-07-17 16:36:49.230 ]: Exception TypeError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (no marshal_dump is defined for class Binding) (process 11397, thread #): ***


        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:141:in `dump'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:141:in `rescue in marshal_exception'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:136:in `marshal_exception'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:584:in `rescue in report_app_init_status'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:561:in `report_app_init_status'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:153:in `initialize_server'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
        from :10:in `synchronize'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /nokia/sa_nmp/home/cotaweb/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.1.2-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `'
*** Exception TypeError in spawn manager (instance of IO needed) (process 11351, thread #):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a very old version of Phusion Passenger. Try Phusion Passenger 4.0.10 (latest release) which has more features and is more stable.

Comment: thanks your comments, but we do have other applications using the version of 3.0.9, so if I upgrade , I have to upgrade the nginx core version, so I have to wait for some feedback from others. However, I will try.